# SELECT on UNION query after LOCK TABLES says table was not locked

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I need to lock a table in a specific area of the code.

So I lock my table with :

`LOCK TABLE christmas_game WRITE;`

That works fine.

Now I need to `SELECT` stuff on this table so I do this :

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE prize
FROM christmas_game
WHERE user_id = {$this->user_id}
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT 2
```

Which works fine too. But this doesn't work at all for some reason :

```
SELECT prize
FROM christmas_game
WHERE DATE(created_at) = CURDATE()
AND user_id != '{$uniqId}'
GROUP BY prize
UNION
SELECT prize
FROM christmas_game
WHERE user_id = {$user->user_id}
AND user_id != '{$uniqId}'
AND prize IN ('promo_1', 'promo_2')
```

There I get an error saying : `Table 'christmas_game' was not locked with LOCK TABLES`.
Obviously the `UNION` is at fault here since both queries work fine without it.

Why is that ?

Comment: Lock tables is almost never needed; what are you doing?

Comment: I'm making a christmas game for a website that allows people to win prizes, one of them is very high priced and we only have one in stock so I can't afford to make 2 people win, that's why I'm locking tables.

Comment: With InnoDB, use "transactions", not table locks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to lock both table, and you can not lock 2 times same table.

Solution is to add an alias to tables :

`LOCK TABLE christmas_game as table_locked_game_1  WRITE, christmas_game as table_locked_game_2 write;`

Then add the same alias in your Union :

```
    SELECT prize 
    FROM christmas_game as table_locked_game_1 
    WHERE DATE(created_at) = CURDATE() GROUP BY prize 
UNION 
    SELECT prize FROM christmas_game as table_locked_game_2 
    WHERE user_id = 81 
    AND prize IN ('promo_1', 'promo_2')
```